# Why do I get the "TeX capacity exceeded" error with the tcolorbox package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, texcapacity

For a package I wrote (schemabloc - https://ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc) which works fine but I have a problem with the tcolorbox package when I use it to display Tikz code examples.

I extracted from the package the two functions that seem to be causing the problem.
The starred version of the \sbComp*... command systematically displays the error

*TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\pgf@setlengthorig #1#2->\begingroup
\pgfutil@selectfont \pgf@setlengthorig ...*

Can you take a look at the code and see where the problem is coming from (I also have an error with the showexpl package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showexpl))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,shapes.misc}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{tikzexample}[1][]{tikz lower, 
           listing side text, fonttitle=\bfseries,
           bicolor, colback=blue!15!white, colbacklower=white,
           colframe=black, righthand width=0.5\textwidth, #1}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\sbEntree}[2][0,0]{
    \node [coordinate, name=#2] at (#1) {};
\node(#2droite) at (#2){};

}

\newcommand*{\sbCompSum}{\@ifstar\sbCompSumNorm\sbCompSumUsuel}


\newcommand{\sbCompSumUsuel}[7][4]{
    \node [draw, circle,minimum size=2em, right of=#3droite%
,node distance=#1em] (#2) {};
     \node [draw, cross out,minimum size=1.414em,
     right of=#3droite,node distance=#1em] {};
     \node [above of=#2,node distance=0.6em,inner sep=0] {$#4$};
     \node [below of=#2,node distance=0.6em,inner sep=0] {$#5$};
     \node [left of=#2,node distance=0.6em,inner sep=0] {$#6$};
     \node [right of=#2,node distance=0.6em,inner sep=0] {$#7$};
\node (#2droite) at (#2.east){};
\node (#2gauche) at (#2.west){};
}


\newcommand{\sbCompSumNorm}[7][4]{
    \node [draw, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#3,node distance=#1em,] (#2) {};
    \node [ fit=(#2),inner sep=0.5em] (compext)  {};
\node at( compext.75){$#4$};
\node at( compext.-75){$#5$};
\node at( compext.165){$#6$};
\node at( compext.15){$#7$};
\node (#2droite) at (#2.east){};
\node (#2gauche) at (#2.west){};
}


\newcommand*{\sbComp}{\@ifstar\sbCompNorm\sbCompUsuel}
\newcommand{\sbCompUsuel}[3][4]{
\sbCompSum[#1]{#2}{#3}{}{-}{+}{}
}
\newcommand{\sbCompNorm}[3][4]{
\sbCompSum*[#1]{#2}{#3}{}{-}{+}{}
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{E};
\sbComp{C1}{E}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzexample}[title=Commande  , listing outside text, righthand width=0.45\textwidth,]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{E};
\sbComp{C1}{E}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzexample}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{E};
\sbComp*{C1}{E}
\end{tikzpicture}

%---------------------------
% code that doesn't work%
%\begin{tikzexample}[title=Commande  , listing outside text, righthand width=0.45\textwidth,]
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\sbEntree{E};
%\sbComp*{C1}{E}
%\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{tikzexample}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't nest `tikzpicture` environments. `tikz lower` already puts a `tikzpicture` environment around the lower part of the box, so you need to omit this from your code altogether or comment it out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,shapes.misc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{tikzexample}[1][]{%
  tikz lower, 
  listing side text, 
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  bicolor,
  colback=blue!15!white,
  colbacklower=white,
  colframe=black,
  righthand width=0.5\textwidth,
  #1%
}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\sbEntree}[2][0,0]{%
  \node [coordinate, name=#2] at (#1) {};
  \node(#2droite) at (#2){};
}

\newcommand*{\sbCompSum}{\@ifstar\sbCompSumNorm\sbCompSumUsuel}

\newcommand{\sbCompSumUsuel}[7][4]{%
  \node [draw, circle,minimum size=2em, right of=#3droite,node distance=#1em] (#2) {};
  \node [draw, cross out,minimum size=1.414em,right of=#3droite,node distance=#1em] {};
  \node [above of=#2,node distance=0.6em,inner sep=0] {$#4$};
  \node [below of=#2,node distance=0.6em,inner sep=0] {$#5$};
  \node [left of=#2,node distance=0.6em,inner sep=0] {$#6$};
  \node [right of=#2,node distance=0.6em,inner sep=0] {$#7$};
  \node (#2droite) at (#2.east){};
  \node (#2gauche) at (#2.west){};
}

\newcommand{\sbCompSumNorm}[7][4]{%
  \node [draw, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#3,node distance=#1em] (#2) {};
  \node [ fit=(#2),inner sep=0.5em] (compext)  {};
  \node at( compext.75){$#4$};
  \node at( compext.-75){$#5$};
  \node at( compext.165){$#6$};
  \node at( compext.15){$#7$};
  \node (#2droite) at (#2.east){};
  \node (#2gauche) at (#2.west){};
}

\newcommand*{\sbComp}{\@ifstar\sbCompNorm\sbCompUsuel}
\newcommand{\sbCompUsuel}[3][4]{%
  \sbCompSum[#1]{#2}{#3}{}{-}{+}{}%
}
\newcommand{\sbCompNorm}[3][4]{%
  \sbCompSum*[#1]{#2}{#3}{}{-}{+}{}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \sbEntree{E};
  \sbComp{C1}{E}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzexample}[title=Commande  , listing outside text, righthand width=0.45\textwidth,]
%   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbEntree{E};
    \sbComp{C1}{E}
%   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzexample}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \sbEntree{E};
  \sbComp*{C1}{E}
\end{tikzpicture}

%---------------------------
% code that doesn't work%
\begin{tikzexample}[title=Commande  , listing outside text, righthand width=0.45\textwidth,]
%   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbEntree{E};
    \sbComp*{C1}{E}
%   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzexample}

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled pictures outside tcolorboxes]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't directly answer the question.
Why is my code not working but all the others are working as examples?
Furthermore, the objective of the examples is to make the code directly copyable without having to retouch it (here remove the %).

Comment: in fact if I delete tikz lower, it works!

Comment: You get the error for the reason I gave: you've nested `tikzpicture`s. Sometimes you get lucky and this works, but it is highly liable to break resulting in weird errors and/or unanticipated output. In this case, there's some kind of interaction between `fit` and the nesting which (I think) triggers some kind of infinite nesting loop. (TeX runs out group levels to nest at 255.) I didn't investigate what precisely in the `fit` library triggers the error since nested `tikzpicture`s are not intended to be supported, so it isn't surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: Deleting `tikz lower` would be another option. What matters is the not-nesting-`tikzpicture`s :).

Comment: @rpapa I can copy-paste the code without the percentage signs, even when they are there. But if copy-paste is the aim, this is clearly not the best solution and removing `tikz lower` will be clearer. You didn't mention that goal in your question.